# If $f(x)$ is convex. Then, is $\sum_{a \in A}f(x).\alpha_a + \sum_{b \in B}f(x).\beta_b$ also convex

Tags: optimization, proof-explanation, nonlinear-optimization

If $f(x)$ is convex. Then:

1. Is $\sum_{a \in A}f(x).\alpha_a$ also convex?
2. If the answer to first question is yes and $\sum_{a \in A}f(x).\alpha_a$ is convex, is $\sum_{a \in A}f(x).\alpha_a + \sum_{b \in B}f(x).\beta_b$  also convex?

How can I prove them as a lemma?

$f(x)$ is a convex non-linear function and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constant variables.

Comment: $\sum_{a \in A}f(a)*\alpha$ is a constant term, how is that to be understood as a function (of $x$)?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I fix it now.

Comment: Is $*$ the ordinary multiplication? Then in both #1 and #2 you have $C \cdot f(x)$ for some constant $C$, and that is convex if $C \ge 0$.

Comment: Yes, it is ordinary multiplication.   In two I am adding them , how can I prove that it is convex.